# IPhone EAAccessoryManager returns an empty NSArray

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

I am new here and I suspect I am missing something obvious but web searches and reading the
apple docs are not helping.  I'm stuck so here goes.

I have an iphone 4 running IOS 4.2.10 with a Samsung HM1100 bluetooth headset connected.
I am sure it is connected because the iphone general setting say so and the iphone responds
when I push the call button on the HM1100. I can't upgrade to IOS 5 and CBCentralManager yet.
The HM1100 is supposed to be iphone4 compatible (bluetooth version 2.1+EDR).

My iphone app is importing  ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h

and the code has the following lines

```
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager]connectedAccessories];

NSLog( @"acessories %@", accessories);
```

The code compiles and runs successfully on the iphone attached to the Xcode 4 debugger 
on a macbook pro and prints out an empty array as follows.

```
2011-12-27 15:03:25.106 View Switcher[102:307] acessories (
)
```

I expected it to return at least one `EAAccessory` object in the array. I must be doing
something wrong.

thanks,
ab

Answer (score 3):

`EAAccessory` is only for the Made-For-iPod licensed accessories. If it isn't licensed and everything it won't show up in the list. You can't just connect an arbitrary Bluetooth headset or other device.

Comment: Yes, a standard Bluetooth headset is not an MFi-compliant accessory, so it won't show up in the list of connected accessories for the External Accessory framework.

Comment: Thanks. I did read something about MFi compliance but I didn't realize it meant this. Obviously ios knows how to connect to this headset, but is just designed not to pass that info on to my app.

Comment: So I got a "Made for iPhone" Zomm Wireless Leash Plus and got it connected and working with the iPhone. The code shown EAAccessoryManager code shown in my question still doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

As Brad Larson pointed out maybe your accessory uses standard bluetooth profiles (like handsfree profile) so it doesn't shows in the list.